# unparseable date:"null" (at offset 0) android

Tags: java, android, date

I am getting this error , suddenly 
It was working fine before that ,..

My date format "Sep 11 2014  3:31PM"

```
public boolean validateLuckyDrawExpirationDate(String strExpirationDate) throws Exception{                  


            SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa");
            Date expirationDateObj=df.parse(strExpirationDate);
            Date today=new Date();

            boolean isAfter=today.after(expirationDateObj);

            boolean isBefore=today.before(expirationDateObj);

            Log.v("isToday", String.valueOf(isAfter));
            Log.v("isBefore", String.valueOf(isBefore));

            Log.v("Original date", String.valueOf(expirationDateObj));
            Log.v("SimpleDateFormat", String.valueOf(df.format(expirationDateObj)));
            Log.e("startDate...2",strExpirationDate);

            return isBefore;

    }
```

Comment: Your **strExpirationDate** `String` is **null**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question header says you are parsing `null` to this method. This `unparseable date:“null”` you will get because of that.

There is no issue with this method for `Sep 11 2014 3:31PM`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are calling your method `validateLuckyDrawExpirationDate()` with parameter value `Sep 11 2014 3:31PM`?

Try put your code in `try-catch` block :

```
public boolean validateLuckyDrawExpirationDate(String strExpirationDate) throws Exception{                  
    Boolean isBefore = false;
    try{

        SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa");
        Date expirationDateObj=df.parse(strExpirationDate);
        Date today=new Date();

        boolean isAfter=today.after(expirationDateObj);

        isBefore=today.before(expirationDateObj);

        Log.v("isToday", String.valueOf(isAfter));
        Log.v("isBefore", String.valueOf(isBefore));

        Log.v("Original date", String.valueOf(expirationDateObj));
        Log.v("SimpleDateFormat", String.valueOf(df.format(expirationDateObj)));
        Log.e("startDate...2",strExpirationDate);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date is not valid!",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        return isBefore;

}
```